# Displaying HTML in Perl Tag

Tags: html, perl

I have a Perl Script which makes a DB connection and displays the output in HTML format. The data which it's trying to display has tags embedded (<>) in it, hence the HTML does not get displayed. If I open the actual HTML file which the script generates using Notepad, I see the data. However I am unable to display it due to the tags. Any idea how this can be fixed?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use DBI;
use HTML::Escape 'escape_html';

unlink("D:\\Perl32\\scripts\\UndeliveredRAW.html");

my $host = '${Node.Caption}';
my $user = '${USER}';
my $pwd = '${PASSWORD}';
my $driver = "SQL Server";


$dbhslam = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver=$driver;Server=$host;UID=$user;PWD=$pwd") || die "connect failed:";
$sthslam = $dbhslam->prepare("SELECT
  DBA_Reports.dbo.undelivered_raw_host_msgs.ID
  DBA_Reports.dbo.undelivered_raw_host_msgs.MESSAGE
FROM
  DBA_Reports.dbo.undelivered_raw_host_msgs");

$sthslam->execute;
$msg = "Up";
$Count = 0;
$Output = "";
$Temp = "";
$tbl = "<TABLE border=1  bordercolor=orange cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1>";
$tblhd = "<TR><TH>ID</TH><TH>MESSAGE</TH></TR>";

while (my $ref = $sthslam->fetchrow_hashref()) {
       $Count++;
    $Output .= '<TR><TD align=center rowspan=1 valign=top width=1000 height=1000>'
            . $ref->{'ID'}.'</TD>'
            .  '<TD align=center rowspan=1 valign=top width=1000 height=1000>'
            .  escape_html($ref->{'MESSAGE'}).'</TD></TR>';
}

$dbhslam->disconnect;

$Output = "$tbl$tblhd$Output</TABLE>";

my $filename1 = 'D:\\Perl32\\Scripts\\UndeliveredRAW.html';
open(my $fh1, '>', $filename1) or die "Could not open file '$filename1' $!";
print $fh1 "$Output";
close $fh1;

if ($Count > 0) {
    $msg = $Output;
}

print "\nMessage: $msg";
print "\nStatistic: $Count";
```

Desired Output

[image]

Contents of HTML generated
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you need something like [HTML::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Escape) or [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Entities).

Comment: Oh, and always `use strict; use warnings;` in perl scripts.

Comment: Is that a module which needs to be installed?   Saw this error when I tried using it PerlScript Error: Can't locate HTML/Escape.pm in @INC (@INC contains: D:/Perl32/site/lib D:/Perl32/lib .)

Comment: This is what I had added. use HTML::Escape qw/escape_html/;
 escape_html("<,>")

Comment: A sample of generated _HTML_ added to your question could be useful. I've noticed a few inconsistences: 1. variables `$host,$user,$pass,$driver` hold values in single quotes no interpolation taking place, 2. in the loop `$Count++` but never utilized, 3. `$Output = "$Output$Temp";` better to write `$Output .= $Temp;`, Notice: there are better ways to form HTML output in variable what improves readability/simplifies code maintenance.

Comment: Yes, you'd have to install the module.

Comment: The Desired Output is what I am expecting to see. If you notice I have <> in the output hence the actual HTML which is displayed is blank.

Comment: The desired output (html in posted picture) doesn't have anything for web browser  to render (make visible).

Comment: This is called a code injection bug. YOu are inserting text into HTML without first converting to HTML. Like the first comment said, you need to escape certain characters.

Comment: I installed the HTML::Escape module and I have updated the code. It still doesn't work as expected. HTML file has the data, however cannot display it due to < in the output. If I remove < from the output, it displays without any issues. Any ideas what I am still missing.

Comment: *I installed the HTML::Escape module and I have updated the code* - Well, you're now loading the HTML::Escape module, but you're not actually doing anything useful with it. You need to call the `escape_html()` function at some point :-)

Comment: This nicely demonstrates one of the reasons why having raw HTML inside your Perl code is a pretty bad idea. You should look at a templating system. I'd recommend the [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/pod/Template::Toolkit).

Comment: Note that a newer (but unfortunately unreleased) [version of HTML::Escape](https://github.com/tokuhirom/HTML-Escape/blob/master/lib/HTML/Escape.pm#L36) has better documentation that demonstrates that `escape_html()` returns the escaped HTML string - `my $escaped = escape_html("<^o^>");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML has a well-understood mechanism to include characters that would normally be interpreted as special characters. For example, if you want to include a `<` in your HTML, that would normally be seen as starting a new HTML element in your document.

The solution is to replace those problematic characters with HTML entities that represent those characters. For example, `<` should be replaced with `&lt;`. Note that this means the ampersand (`&`) needs to be added to the set of characters that should be replaced (in this case by `&amp;`) if you want to include it in your HTML.

Perl has a long history of being used on the web, so it's no surprise that there are many tools available to carry out this replacement. [HTML::Escape](https://metacpan.org/dist/HTML-Escape) is probably the best known. It supplies a single function (`escape_html()`) which takes a text string and returns that same string with all of the problematic characters replaced by the appropriate entities.

```
use HTML::Escape 'escape_html';

my $html = '<some text> & <some other text>'
my $escaped_html = escape_html($html);
```

After running this code, `$escaped_html` now contains "$lt;some text$gt; $amp; $lt;some other text$gt;". And if you send that text to a browser, you will get the correct output displayed.

So the easiest solution is to load HTML::Escape at the top of your program and then call `escape_html()` whenever you're adding potentially problematic strings to your output. That means your `while` loop would look something like this:

```
while (my $ref = $sthslam->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    $Count++;
    $Output .= '<TR><TD align=center rowspan=1 valign=top width=5000 height=5000>'
            .  escape_html($ref->{'MESSAGE'})
            .  '</TD></TR>';
}
```

Note that I've removed the `$Temp` variable (which didn't seem to be doing anything useful) and switched to using `.=` to build up your output string. `=.` is the "assignment concatenation" operator - it adds the new string on its right to the end of whatever currently exists in the variable on its left.

You seem to be learning Perl on the job (which is great) but it's a real shame that you're learning it in an environment that seems to use techniques that have been outdated for about twenty years. Your question is a good example of why trying to build up raw HTML strings inside your Perl code is a bad idea. It's a far better idea to use a templating engine of some kind (the defacto standard in the Perl world seems to be [the Template Toolkit](https://tt2.org/)).

I also recommend looking at Cascading Style Sheets as a more modern approach to styling your HTML output.

Comment: Thank you so much Dave for your detailed explanation. Had one last question. I need to add another column ID  in the output. This column does not need any escape function. I add ID to the while loop however ran into issues. Can you let me know what I am missing?

Comment: @SQLNovice: *Can you let me know what I am missing?* - That's impossible without knowing a lot more about the problem. For example, what are the issues you're having? Honestly, this sounds like a new problem, so I recommend asking it as a new question.

Comment: I was able to find the issue and I have updated the code. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Following code snippet demonstrates slightly modified version of posted code.

Please see the loop section for `escape_html(...)` usage on database obtained data.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use DBI;
use HTML::Escape qw/escape_html/;

my $filename = 'D:\Perl32\scripts\UndeliveredRAW.html';

unlink($filename) if -e $filename;

my $host = ${Node.Caption};
my $user = ${USER};
my $pwd  = ${PASSWORD};
my $driver = 'SQL Server';

my $dbh = DBI->connect("dbi:ODBC:Driver=$driver;Server=$host;UID=$user;PWD=$pwd")
        or die 'DB connect failed:';
my $query = '
SELECT
  DBA_Reports.dbo.undelivered_raw_host_msgs.MESSAGE
FROM
  DBA_Reports.dbo.undelivered_raw_host_msgs
';

my $rv = $dbh->do($query) or die $dbh->errstr;

my $msg   = 'Up';
my $Count = 0;

my $tbl = '
<TABLE border=1 bordercolor=orange cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1>
        <TR><TH>MESSAGE</TH></TR>
';

while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    $Count++; 
    $tbl .= "\n\t<TR><TD align=center rowspan=1 valign=top width=5000 height=5000>"
          . escape_html($ref->{'MESSAGE'})
          . '</TD></TR>';
}

$tbl .= '
</TABLE>
';

my $html = 
'<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Undelivered RAW</title>
    </head>
    <body>
         <h1>DB table data</h1>
' . $tbl . '
    </body>
</html>
';

open my $fh, '>', $filename
     or die "Could not open file '$filename1' $!";
print $fh $html;
close $fh;

if ($Count > 0) {
    say 'Message:   ' . $msg;
    say 'Statistic: ' . $Count";
}
```

Note: to avoid polluting code with *HTML style* attributes find some time to learn CSS, your generated *HTML* does not include required sections *DOCTYPE*, *html*, *head*, *title*, *body*

Reference:

- [DBI](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI)
- [HTML::Escape](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::Escape)
- [DBI/DBD::ODBC Tutorial](https://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/perl/dbd_odbc_tutorial_part_1.html)
- [CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/)
- [HTML](https://www.w3schools.com/html/)